# NSWindow display alert when attempt to close

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsalert

How can I display an NSAlert when an NSWindow attempts to close?  This will also have to be turned on and off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSWindow's delegate has a [windowShouldClose:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowShouldClose:) method that will allow you to customize this. There's also NSWindow's documentEdited methods that let you mark a document as having unsaved changes, which might interest you.

Comment: Note that if your window is part of a document based app you will already get an alert sheet by default if you try to close a window whose document is marked as dirty, meaning there are unsaved changes. (Influenced by window restoration, auto save APIs also)